# classification of quadratically factorable fields

Tags: abstract-algebra

Let $F$ be a field such that any polynomial in $F$ of degree two or more has a quadratic factor. For a given fixed characteristic, is there a classification of such fields?

For example, both $\bar{\mathbb{Q}}$ (the algebraic closure of the rationals) and $\bar{\mathbb{Q}}\cap\mathbb{R}$ are such fields for characteristic $0$.

Comment: Algebraically closed fields have an even stronger condition: they fully split into linear factors.

Comment: I agree however I am interested in classifying this larger class of fields which contains as a subset the algebraically closed field